# "how i can return to the same tab where i left after i submit a form."

Tags: jquery

This is the current jquery that i am using for my tabs. Any help would be appreciated, Thank you in advance.

```
<script src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $(".tabs").not(":first").hide();

        $(".tab .control a").click(function(){
            storage = $(this).attr("href");
            $(".tabs").hide();
            $(storage).show();
        });
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: Be more detailed in question. Are you submitting the form and then navigating out of the page.

Comment: no im submitting the form and after submitting the form its redirecting me to the first tab instead of the last tab i was in.

Comment: you possibly need to put some value into the querystring when the page renders again after form submission, which you can use to open the correct tab. Or a cookie, or localStorage or something. However you implemement it, you need to persist that value for yourself, because when you submit a form it refreshes the whole page, as if the previous version of the page never existed.

Comment: can you do a demo using my code, if that's not too much to asked.